# CheckComboBox: how do i display the list of selected items?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatemplate

I am using [Extended WPF Toolkit's](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CheckComboBox&referringTitle=Home) `CheckComboBox`. Binding is working fine. While using custom `ItemTemplate`, how do I display the selected names 
jane - teacher, john - developer, joe - nurse
 in the `Text` property? Using `DisplayMemberPath` with `ItemTemplate` does not work.

```
<xctk:CheckComboBox ItemsSource="{ Binding Path=Customers }" Delimiter="," 
                    ValueMemberPath="Id" SelectedValue="{ Binding SelectedCustomerIds }" 
                    ItemTemplate="{ StaticResource ccBTemplate }" />​

<DataTemplate x:Key="ccBTemplate ">
  <TextBlock Text="{ Binding Path=Name }" />
  <TextBlock Text="{ Binding Path=JobTitle }" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: can you provide more information as to what does your object structure looks like in terms of data?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by `the selected items is not displayed in the checkcombobox like it was while using displaymemberpath`.  What exactly do you see?

Comment: Add DisplayMemberPath to `<xctk:CheckComboBox  DisplayMemberPath="Name" .../>`

Answer (score 0):

The `Text` property takes all `SelectedItems`, converts them to a text by calling `ToString()` on them and finally joins them with `Delimiter`.

So you only need to override `ToString()` on your customer class as follows

```
public override string ToString
{
    return Name + " - " + Job;
}
```